# Listings numbering in Appendix

Tags: listings, numbering

Currently, I have an issue that in my thesis the numbering of listings in the appendix is not as desired. I currently only get *Listing 1* as the numbering of the first listing in the first Appendix, instead of *Listing A.1*. For figures and tables, I already achieve the desired behavior, that is, the figures and tables get, for instance, the following numbering: *Figure A.1*.

I just discovered that at the appendix I use the following Latex commands to, obviously, control the behavior of figure and table numbering:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

What do I have to add to get this to work for listings in the appendix?

Comment: okay the following command seems to do the trick for me: `\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
`

Comment: You should use `\thesection` as part of `\thefigure`, `\thetable` and `\thelstlisting`, not `\Alph{section}`. That implies a recursive definition which will change with every change to `\thesection`.

Comment: @beta: Please give some feedback to the solution whether this is what you requested!

Comment: as i said in my comment (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315056/listings-numbering-in-appendix?noredirect=1#comment768768_315056) I found a solution. can this be converted to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The `\counterwithin` command from `chngcntr` package does the correct setup without explicit `\renewcommand` statements of `\the....` macros.

The only macro that has to be redefined is `\thesection` in order to use `\Alph{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}
}



\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Foo}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption={Foo listing}]

#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```